# Query strip is removed from open graph url

Tags: query-string, facebook-opengraph

In relation to this question: [Dynamic generation of Facebook Open Graph meta tags](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8431694/dynamic-generation-of-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags/8788999#8788999)

I have followed these instructions but the api seems to remove my query string so that the url passed into the aggregation contains none of my dynamic information. If I enter the url with the query string into the debugger it doesn't remove it and works fine. I can confirm my og:url meta tag does also contain the same query string not just the base url.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Im experiencing the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Just solved the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378534/facebook-post-with-parameters/15387232#15387232

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue and solved it like this:

So assuming you're doing your post request like it shows in the [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/), youre Javascript probably looks something like this:

```
  function postNewAction()
  {
      passString = '&object=http://yoursite.com/appnamespace/object.php';

      FB.api('/me/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION' + passString,'post',
         function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                  alert(response.error.message);
              } 
              else {
                  alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
              } 
          }
      );    
  }
```

And since you say you want to generate meta tags dynamically, you're probably adding a parameter to the url (passString) there like so:

```
  passString = '&object=http://yoursite.com/appnamespace/object.php?user=' + someuser;
```

This is wrong.

What you need to do is to make the url a 'pretty url' and use htaccess to decipher it. So:

```
  passString = '&object=http://yoursite.com/appnamespace/object/someuser';
```

Then your htaccess file will tell your site that that url actually equates to

```
  http://yoursite.com/appnamespace/object/object.php?user=someuser
```

Then you can use GET to store the user parameter with php and insert it however you like into your meta tags.

In case youre wondering, in the og:url meta tag's content will be:

```
  $url = 'http://yoursite.com/appnamespace/object/object.php?user=' . $_GET[$user];
```

Does that help?

Comment: helped me... gosh this dumb "feature" of theirs is annoying to work with