# Facebook post with parameters

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to make a Facebook post with parameters. I used solutions from here: 
[Generating Facebook Open Graph meta tags dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431694/dynamic-generation-of-facebook-open-graph-meta-tags?rq=1) and here: [Dynamic Facebook og Meta Tags in Wordpress PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075694/dynamic-facebook-og-meta-tags-in-wordpress-php?lq=1)

THE FINAL WORKING CODE:

```
<?php

$params = array();
if(count($_GET) > 0) {
    $params = $_GET;
} else {
    $params = $_POST;
}
// defaults
if($params['title'] == "") $params['title'] = "default_title";
if($params['score'] == "") $params['score'] = "1234567";

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# pathoflight: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/pathoflight#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id"         content="MY_APP_ID" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"           content="pathoflight:level" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"            content="<?php echo 'https://path-of-light.herokuapp.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/>
  <meta property="og:image"          content="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"          content="<?php echo $params['title']; ?>" /> 
  <meta property="pathoflight:score" content="<?php echo $params['score']; ?>" />
</head>
```

It works perfect in browser and Facebook Debugger, but my posts via Facebook API Explorer always leads to default values for `title` and `score`. How can I tell Facebook to read my *real* parameters?

Comment: The url in your error does not show any value for title or score. Are you sure you are passing correct values while making the post?
"https://path-of-light.herokuapp.com/level_new.php?title=&score="

Comment: @VishweshShetty Yes, I'm sure. I make a post like this in Facebook Graph Explorer:
me/pathoflight:complete?level=https://path-of-light.herokuapp.com/level_new.php?title=my_title&score=567765

Comment: Can u try using 'add field' option and then use this value -> 'https://path-of-light.herokuapp.com/level_new.php?title=my_title&score=567765' for 'level' instead of passing level as parameter in the url.

Comment: @VishweshShetty The result is the same. I' came further and updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue also was that Facebook API Explorer skips parameters if you make a post like this

```
me/pathoflight:complete?level=https://path-of-light.herokuapp.com/level_new.php?title=my_title&score=223322
```

This approach works:

```
me/pathoflight:complete
Add a field
level     https://path-of-light.herokuapp.com/level_new.php?title=my_title&score=223322
```